# Стилизованный инпут файл не срабатывает после первого нажатия на него

Tags: javascript, html, input

Пытаюсь сделать стилизованный инпут файл, чтобы при нажатии его лэйбл менялся на название приложенного файла. Однако после первого нажатия, второй раз нажать уже не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
function ready() {
    const inputFile = document.querySelector('.reg-box_file');
    const labelFile = document.querySelector('.screen-label');
    const labelValue = labelFile.textContent
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
        let fileName = this.files[0].name
        if (fileName) {
            labelFile.textContent = fileName
            labelFile.classList.add('screen-label__active') 
        } else {
            labelFile.innerHTML = labelValue
        }
    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
```

html:

```
<div class="screen-container">
       <label class="screen-label" for="screen-file">
              <input
              class="reg-box reg-box_file"
              id="screen-file"
              type="file"
              />
         Прикрепить скриншот</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажи свой html... Скорее всего проблема в том, что твой инпут находится внутри label и по факт ты из DOM удалешь инпут и вставляешь обратно.. В итоге и слушатель пропадает. И надо либо слушатель восстанавливать, либо более корреткно в label менять именно текст, а не всё содержимое

Comment: Да, html такой же, как вы описали. А можете привести пример корректного изменения текста в label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно убрать инпут из `label`, а можно обернуть текст в какой-нибудь `span` и работать с ним:

```js
function ready() {
    const DEFAULT_FILE_NAME = 'Файл не выбран';

    const inputFile = document.querySelector('.reg-box_file');
    const labelFile = document.querySelector('.screen-label');
    let fileName = labelFile.querySelector('.file-name');
    fileName.textContent = DEFAULT_FILE_NAME
    
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
        fileName.textContent = DEFAULT_FILE_NAME
        
        if (this.files[0]) {
            fileName.textContent = this.files[0].name
            labelFile.classList.add('screen-label__active') 
        }
    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  width: 118px
}
```

```html
<div class="screen-container">
       <label class="screen-label" for="screen-file">
              <input
              class="reg-box reg-box_file"
              id="screen-file"
              type="file"
              />
         <span class="file-name"></span></label>
</div>
```

Тут на самом деле всё зависит от того, хочется ли, чтобы инпут реагировал при клике на label или нет. Хочется ли, чтобы вся строка была "активной" или только определённая часть

Answer (score 0):

Надо инпут убрать из тега label.
Пример:

```
<div class="screen-container">
       <label class="screen-label" for="screen-file">
         Прикрепить скриншот</label>
         <input class="reg-box reg-box_file"
         id="screen-file" type="file"/>
</div>
```